# While updating distribution gradle version to 7.6.1 getting error

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

When try to update distribution gradle url to

```
https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6.1-bin.zip
```

getting below error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':buildSrc:generateExternalPluginSpecBuilders'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':buildSrc:compileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2.
     Required by:
         project :buildSrc
      > No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 was found. The consumer was configured to find an API of a library compatible with Java 8, preferably not packaged as a jar, preferably optimized for standard JVMs, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.6.1', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'jvm' but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares an API of a library, packaged as a jar, preferably optimized for standard JVMs, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'jvm':
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6.1')
          - Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for standard JVMs)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them preferably not packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6.1')
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type (required 'jvm')
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a runtime of a library, packaged as a jar, preferably optimized for standard JVMs, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'jvm':
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6.1')
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for standard JVMs)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them preferably not packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6.1')
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type (required 'jvm')
* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 2s
> Task :buildSrc:generateExternalPluginSpecBuilders FAILED
1 actionable task: 1 executed
*********************************************
            Static Analysis Failed           
Please fix the above issues before committing
*********************************************
```

Things I checked so far to resolve it

- Cleared the gradle caches
- Checked JDK supported version (It's 11)

Versions

- Android studio version (Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 2)
- gradle version (7.4.2)
- Mac version (13.1)
- git version (2.37.1)

Answer (score 14):

I had the same error!

Do it:

In the **android/build.gradle** file, change the dependencies line to "gradle:7.4.2":

```
dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2")
    }
```

In the **android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties**, change the version of gradle:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6.1-bin.zip
```

Go to the **android** directory and run the command:

```
./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version=7.6.1
```

Hope this fixes it and helps you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Dino.. Ignore the bot, your answer is perfect

Answer (score 0):

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.2'
                                                  ^
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

for me the solution was to let AndroidStudio figure out the gradle class path, so going to the colon: and ctrl+space (autocomplete, and it gives available valid options)